# ReactJS - Material UI icon not rendering in browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

[image]

Hi, I am trying use material ui but i got this huge list of errors. I did several installs and uninstalls of node, npm modules, etc. but I only can render everything else in browser, but not the icons.

Thanks

Comment: Add the code for App.js as well

Comment: I advise you to delete the node_modules folder and try installing new packages via `npm install` from the root. Might be issues with packages.

Comment: You are right @Yash it was some stupid npm packages conflict. After hours searching for answers I wrote in cmd npm ls and then I deleted every single package, because install/uninstall, clear cache, etc didn't work.